# How to change icon in Archive before submit app to App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, app-store

How to set this image?

Xcode->Organizer->Archives

[image]

I have alredy set icon here

[image]

Icon.png (57x57)

Icon@2x.png (114x114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your project settings and add icons here:
[image: Project Settings are where you can easily add icons]

Make sure the icons are properly sized for regular and retina displays. [Apple documentation can be found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Comment: Yes, i have alredy do that. But it doesn't dispay on Organizer->Archive

Comment: It may be that your icons aren't sized correctly, or they are not being included in the archive for some reason.  If you quit Xcode and relaunch and re-create the archive, do you have better results?

Comment: Clean, delete the app from the devices/simulator - build again